# How to make Skype calls work with an Azure functions bot?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-functions

I am working on a bot which you can message and call via Skype. The bot runs in Azure functions. I have the message part working. I have configured the bot in Azure to have calling capabilities and I can call the bot, but it returns a spoken message that "You can't talk to this bot just yet, but we are working on it".

I followed [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/skype-CallingBot) github example to make a bot. I exchanged the controllers for Azure functions. [image: Azure calling function]
When I press the call button in Skype I do see my function being reached in the Azure portal, but I get the following error in my logs:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : 
Exception while executing function: call 
---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. 
Registration: Activator = ICallingBot (DelegateActivator), 
Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.ICallingBot], 
Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, 
Sharing = Shared, 
Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope 
---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: 
Activator = CallingBotService (DelegateActivator), 
Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.CallingBotService, Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.ICallingBotService], 
Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, 
Sharing = Shared, 
Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope 
---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. 
Registration:
Activator = CallingBotServiceSettings (DelegateActivator), 
Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.CallingBotServiceSettings], 
Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, 
Sharing = Shared, 
Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope 
---> Bot calling configuration is invalid, callback url:  is not a valid url! 
(See inner exception for details.) 
(See inner exception for details.) 
(See inner exception for details.) 
---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : 
An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. 
Registration: Activator = CallingBotService (DelegateActivator), 
Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.CallingBotService, 
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.ICallingBotService], 
Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, 
Sharing = Shared, 
Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope 
---> An error occurred du…
```

It seems to be complaining about a callback url, which I indeed could not find how to set. I tried supplying it in the local.settings.json file under the key "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.CallbackUrl", but that did not help.

Is it actually possible to process Skype calls using an Azure functions bot? And if yes, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1:**

Adding the callback in the Application settings removed the error I was getting in the logs. Unfortunately, the Skype bot still replies with: "You can't talk to this bot just yet, but we are working on it". I have posted this issue on [this github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4677) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future people: We ultimately decided on not using Azure Functions for a Calling bot as it simply seems to be impossible.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4677

Answer (score 3):

The callback URL is expected to be set as an App Setting. Please go to your Function App and under **Overview** > **Application Settings** > **Application Settings Section**, add a new setting named `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.CallbackUrl`

Comment: This indeed solved the errors in the logs. However, the bot still returns a spoken "You can't talk to this bot just yet, but we are working on it", and now I don't have any error messages to go on. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Without additional error information, it's difficult to provide any guidance. Adding some logging to your function, and adding a try/catch to some of the calls you're making may help better understand what is going on.

Comment: I am not sure what extra logging I could do. What I do know from the logs is that the events (OnIncomingCallReceived, OnPlayPromptCompleted, etc) are being attached, but the corresponding functions are never invoked.